# excel match 2 columns to sort a third

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a datasheet like this:

```
First   Second                                      Third   Fourth
B159    top_8,top_9,top_10,top_11                   B159    GRAND PRIX CAP
B185    top_12,top_13,top_14                        B159    GRAND PRIX CAP
B186    top_15,top_16                               B159    GRAND PRIX CAP
B244    top_17,top_18,top_19,top_20,top_21,top_22   B159    GRAND PRIX CAP
B285    top_24,top_25,top_26,top_27,top_28          B185    BALL MARK GOLF CAP
B291    top_29,top_30,top_31,top_32,top_33          B185    BALL MARK GOLF CAP
B295    top_34,top_35                               B185    BALL MARK GOLF CAP
B296    top_36,top_37,top_38,top_39                 B186    TACTEL® PERFORMANCE CAP
B34     top_43,top_44,top_45,top_46                 B186    TACTEL® PERFORMANCE CAP
B345    top_47,top_48,top_49,top_50,top_51,top_52   B244    SUMMIT HAT
B38     top_53,top_54                               B244    SUMMIT HAT
B445    top_55,top_56                               B244    SUMMIT HAT
B446B   top_57,top_58,top_59,top_60,top_61          B244    SUMMIT HAT
B447    top_62,top_63,top_64                        B244    SUMMIT HAT
B44C    top_65,top_66,top_67                        B244    SUMMIT HAT
```

first column gives me a group id, second column are the items in that group. third column are all the group id's and all the product names.

now what i'd like to do is find the first column(b159) match it with the third column so i can sort out which name which group should have.

so the end result would look something like

```
First   Second                      Third   Fourth
B159    top_8,top_9,top_10,top_11   B159    GRAND PRIX CAP
B185    top_12,top_13,top_14        B185    BALL MARK GOLF CAP
B186    top_15,top_16               B186    TACTEL® PERFORMANCE CAP
```

I've tried it with `vlookup`, `match` and all the things I could find but nothing does with I'd like to do. This is something I had tried:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,A1:D15,4)
```

but this just returns the same value as in the fourth column. Does someone know how I could solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can spot three things:-

(1) Should be looking up in column C not A

(2) Need to put dollar signs in

(3) Probably need to put 'false' to make sure you get the right match.

All that would lead to:-

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,C$1:D$15,2,false)
```

Then you should really put in some error checking in case there is no match:-

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,C$1:D$15,2,false),"No Match")
```

Comment: You may start with row 2, and indicate where to place the formula.

Comment: yes you where right, i had also thought about this but the first time i didn't use A in the search array it would give me an error strangely. could you tell me the use of the dollar signs ?

Comment: Yes of course, if you don't put them in when you pull the formula down to the next row it will give =VLOOKUP(a2,C2:D16,2,false) so it will miss out the first row of the lookup columns. The dollar signs anchor it to the top row.